# how to reorder skipping numbers in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

when I register banner, I have to set banner's sort order by select box(that is banner List's length + 1)

if I registered 5 banners(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) then after delete 2 banner (2, 4) then 3 banners (1, 3, 5)left . and I have to reorder it to 1, 2, 3 in sql after delete it.

because when I update banner that's sort order is 5, it cannot show this because select box is fixed to banner list's length +1

and when I want to register the new banner in the end (number 4), it can't be in the end because 5 is existed already.

I have no Idea to try this

Comment: which dbms (mysql, sql-server, oracle, prostgres) and version of dbms your are using?

Comment: I'm using oracle

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update the column, you need a sequence

Create a `sequence` to handle the id's. Use the sequence nextval when inserting new rows.

```
create sequence bannerseq
  MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;
```

Then your insert will be:

```
insert into banner (id, othercols)
values (bannerseq.nextval, 'Somevalue');
```

This helps to mitigate against breaking foreign keys.